# ASP.Net Identity 2.1 inside MVC5 application using Unity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unity-container, asp.net-identity

I'm upgrading my ASP.Net MVC5 application from Identity 1 to 2.1.
After one day I made it run... but I can't verify roles for my users (by IsInRole or Authorize Attribute).
I guess it is because MVC doesn't resolve the user and role manager since my application uses Unity DI and Identity 2 seems to be based on OwinContext with the following configuration :

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
```

Is there a simple way, tutorial or documentation to have Identity 2 working with external dependency injection ?

[Edit]
Now Unity DI seems to work a little (thanks to meep).

I modified Startup.Auth.cs, adding to ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) function :

```
var container = UnityConfig.Container;
var dbContext = container.Resolve<ApplicationDbContext>();

container.RegisterInstance<IAppBuilder>(app, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
container.RegisterType<UserManager<ApplicationUser>, ApplicationUserManager>();
container.RegisterType<IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string>, RoleStore<IdentityRole>>();
container.RegisterType<RoleManager<IdentityRole>, ApplicationRoleManager>();

// [Edit 2]
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationDbContext>((options, owinContext) => container.Resolve<ApplicationDbContext>());
app.CreatePerOwinContext<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>((options, owinContext) => container.Resolve<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>());
app.CreatePerOwinContext<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>((options, owinContext) => container.Resolve<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>());
```

In my UnitiConfig.cs file I added the declaration for a Container singleton (used above).

In IdentityConfig.cs, I dropped the Create method and changed the ctor for

```
public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store, ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
        : base(store)
{
    this.Initialize(dbContext);
}

private void Initialize(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
{
    // Configurer la logique de validation pour les noms d'utilisateur
    this.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(this)
    {
        AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
        RequireUniqueEmail = true
    };
    // ... more code...
}

public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<IdentityRole>
{
    public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string> roleStore)
        : base(roleStore)
    {
    }
}
```

I can authenticate the users... but UserManager.GetRoles() is always empty.
Moreover [Authorize(Roles="myrole"] rejects every user...

Comment: Not much to it, really. Just register your `ApplicationUserManager`, `ApplicationRoleManager`, `ApplicationSignInManager` and `ApplicationDbContext` in your DI container. Beware that Identity still needs Owin registration for `ApplicationDbContext` and for `ApplicationUserManager`, so keep it present.

Comment: not simple in fact. I had it half work using the links given by "meep", but my UserManager.GetRoles() is always empty... even through UserManager.IsInRole returns true. Nevertheless [Authorize(Roles="Admin")] always denies access...

Comment: How can I register ApplicationDbContext and ApplicationUserManager into Owin using the DI resolution (I don't want to create a context for DI and another for Owin) ?

Comment: I used `app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(DependencyResolver.GetService<ApplicationUserManager>());`. Not very familiar with Unity, but this works with Autofac and SimpleInjector.

Comment: If you not getting roles from `UserManager.GetRoles()`, can you check if roles are actually assigned in the database?

Comment: I had some tests with app.CreatePerOwinContext that didn't even compile because the callback I was giving to the lamdba where not good. Fixing it made it compile (Edit2).

Comment: For GetRole, yes there are roles linked to the users. It worked with Identity 1. When querying directly the SQL Server Database I can find it.

Comment: Nevertheless, IsInRole works fine now !

Comment: Does your app use cookie authentication, and if so, did you have to do anything with the `app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions{ Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider { OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator... } }` section of code in `Startup.Auth.cs`?

Comment: And in your second param to `ApplicationUserManager`, did you really pass in the `ApplicationDbContext`? I thought the `IOwinContext` would have been more appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK... Thank you all !
I got it !

By profiling the query send to SQL Server (using Express Profiler) I saw that EF tryed to join Roles Table On a column named IdentityUser_Id.
Back to the table definition in SQL Server I saw 2 fields :
- UserId containing the ids
- IdentityUser_Id... always null !
So that's why my Roles were always empty !

But why theses 2 columns for the same data ?

I took a look at the EF migration file. Here were some strange lines :

```
RenameColumn(table: "dbo.T_Securite_AspNetUserClaims", name: "User_Id", newName: "IdentityUser_Id");
AddColumn("dbo.T_Securite_AspNetUserLogins", "IdentityUser_Id", c => c.String(maxLength: 128));
AddColumn("dbo.T_Securite_AspNetUserRoles", "IdentityUser_Id", c => c.String(maxLength: 128));
```

So it looks like the EF Migration generator was lost.
I changed the OnModelCreating method for ApplicationDbContext to help it a little by telling where the foreign keys are actually :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>()
            .ToTable("T_Security_AspNetUsers"); // Yes... I changed the table name : maybe the source of the problem !

modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>()
            .HasMany(u => u.Roles)
            .WithOptional()
            .HasForeignKey(r => r.UserId);

modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>()
            .HasMany(u => u.Logins)
            .WithOptional()
            .HasForeignKey(l => l.UserId);

modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>()
            .HasMany(u => u.Claims)
            .WithOptional()
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.UserId);
```

Now the EF Migration file is looking better.
I have roles for my users and the [Authorize(Role="xxx")] seems to work !

Comment: Great! glad you found the solution!